# Counting characters in a shell script using WC

Tags: command, shell-exec, strlen, wc

I am writing a shell script command which counts the characters typed.
I am using `wc`. My script is `echo $1 | wc -c`. The problem is that it is counting a +1 character. For example, if i type 'hello' it displays (6) characters typed but it should display (5). Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the shell you're using, you could do this:

```
$ var='hello'
$ echo ${#var}
5
```

This way you don't need to call an external program.

Comment: echo $1 | wc -L
what this does is, it Prints the maximum line length.